# Apply trained BERT model for prediction deployment

Tags: python, multilabel-classification, bert-language-model

I'm currently working on **multi-label classification** task for **text data**.
I have a dataframe with an ID column, text column and several columns which are text label containing only 1 or 0.

I used an existing solution proposed on this website [Kaggle Toxic Comment Classification using Bert](https://www.kaggle.com/javaidnabi/toxic-comment-classification-using-bert/output) which permits to express in percentage its degree of belonging to each label.

Now, that I've train my model I would like to test it on few text extracts with no label in order to obtain percentage of belonging to each label :

I've tried this solution :

```
def getPrediction(in_sentences):
  label = ['S1, S2, S3']
  input_examples = [run_classifier.InputExample(guid="", text_a = x, text_b = None, label=label) for x in in_sentences]
  input_features = run_classifier.convert_examples_to_features(input_examples, LABEL_COLUMNS, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, tokenizer)
  predict_input_fn = run_classifier.input_fn_builder(features=input_features, seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, is_training=False, drop_remainder=False)
  predictions = estimator.predict(predict_input_fn)
  return [(sentence, prediction['probabilities'], labels[prediction['labels']]) for sentence, prediction in zip(in_sentences, predictions)]

pred_sentences = [
  "here is an exemple of sentence"]

pred_sentences = ''.join(pred_sentences)

predictions = getPrediction(pred_sentences)
```

And I got :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-490-770bf0871d3e> in <module>
----> 1 predictions = getPrediction(pred_sentences)

<ipython-input-486-3de7328d60db> in getPrediction(in_sentences)
      2   label = ['S1','S2',
      3    'S3']
----> 4   input_examples = [run_classifier.InputExample(guid="", text_a = x, text_b = None, labels=label) for x in in_sentences]
      5   input_features = run_classifier.convert_examples_to_features(input_examples, LABEL_COLUMNS, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, tokenizer)
      6   predict_input_fn = run_classifier.input_fn_builder(features=input_features, seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, is_training=False, drop_remainder=False)

<ipython-input-486-3de7328d60db> in <listcomp>(.0)
      2   label = ['S1,
      3    S2,S3']
----> 4   input_examples = [run_classifier.InputExample(guid="", text_a = x, text_b = None, labels=label) for x in in_sentences]
      5   input_features = run_classifier.convert_examples_to_features(input_examples, LABEL_COLUMNS, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, tokenizer)
      6   predict_input_fn = run_classifier.input_fn_builder(features=input_features, seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, is_training=False, drop_remainder=False)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'
```

Any idea what I need to change to make the last part of my algorithm functional?

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo, `InputExample` expects a keyword argument named `label`,  not `labels`:

```
[run_classifier.InputExample(guid="", text_a = x, text_b = None, labels=label) for x in in_sentences]
                                                                      ^
```

Comment: In fact, I've already try that but I got the error :                                         TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: That is because the keyword argument `label` expects a string, not a list. See https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_classifier.py#L139

Comment: I've tried to add :   def getPrediction(in_sentences):
  label = ["S1","S2","S3""]
  label = " ".join(str(x) for x in label)  which permit to transform the list in string but I still get an error : KeyError: 'S1 S2 S3'

Comment: `InputExample` is for **single** training/test example, so should only a receive a single label.

Comment: See the `Data Preprocessing` step in this notebook: https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb

Comment: I'm using the same code available on this website : https://www.kaggle.com/javaidnabi/toxic-comment-classification-using-bert/output

Comment: but it is different from the code available on Github https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb (which permits to test the trained algorithm on new sentences).

Comment: My goal here is to adapt the part code starting by "def getPrediction(in_sentences):" to my main algorithm (Kaggle one). To my mind, the major difference is that in the Github code, they take into account only one label_columns but with a new variable "label_list", in my main code I have many label_columns and no label_list.

Comment: So I tried to change for example label_list parameter in label_columns, I've also tried to change label = 0 in label = labels where labels = [S1, S2, S3] but in this last example I had an error saying that the variable label can take only string as you mentioned so I tried to convert this list in string with  : labels = ''.join(labels) but I got "KeyError: 'S1S2S3'.

Comment: Finally, I also tried : label='S1' (which is none sense in my case because i have 3 labels but not only one)  but I got "ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((?, 3) vs (?,))"